# Jest spyOn useMutation with mocked data

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-query

```
it('should execute custom onSuccess callback', async () => {
    const onSuccess = jest.fn();
    const spyQuery = jest.spyOn(ReactQuery, 'useMutation').mockReturnValue({mutate: onSuccess});
    const user = userEvent.setup();
    const contextValue = { user: mockedUser, folders: mockedFolders };
    render(<main role="main"></main>);
    renderWithAllProviders(
      <AddressBookProvider {...contextValue}>
        <AddToAddressBook />
      </AddressBookProvider>
    );

 //data to submit//

    const submitButton = screen.getByRole('button', {
      name: /MOBILE_WEB_GENERAL_DONE/i,
    });

    await user.click(submitButton);

    expect(spyQuery).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

I need to `spyOn` "useMutation" but I am getting

```
Argument of type '{ mutate: jest.Mock<any, any>; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UseMutationResult<unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown>'.
```

I need to use my mock data from `mockedUser` and `mockedFolders`
any help with this, as I am brand new to jest testing

Comment: Don't mock `useMutation` hook, use this way, see https://tanstack.com/query/v3/docs/react/guides/testing#testing-network-calls